# Why is this expression not evaluating properly?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to evaluate the following expression in C++. I'm using Visual Studio (current release) if that makes any difference.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

std::cout << (1.686 * 1000 / (4 / 3) / M_PI / (pow(0.015, 3)) / 3340);
```

Now when I execute the program the output is:

**47608.8**

Whereas if I use WolframAlpha the expression is evaluated to:
[image: Wolfram's result]

I've also tried breaking down each portion of the expression to check if things like the "pow()" function is working correctly or if M_PI is accurate but everything seems to be consistent up until I evaluate everything at once.

***Am I missing something, why am I getting an incorrect answer?***

I've been looking at this code for quite a while now and I can't seem to figure out what's going on. I'm thinking it might be some sort of precision error?

Comment: because in c++ `4 / 3` is `1`

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I feel ridiculous. I haven't programmed for a while and I just assumed something as simple as 4/3 would be correct.

Comment: Since 4 and 3 are integers, you get integer division. In integer division,  the correct answer for four divided by three *is* one, remainder one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(4 / 3)
```

This sub-expression has two integer arguments, so it will be done with integer math. The result of the division is truncated, so instead of `1.333333f` the result is `1`.

You can fix it by making one or both numbers floating point constants.

```
(4.0 / 3.0)
```